# How to speed up confint in R

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing, confidence-interval

I have a question concerning the native `confint` function in R. Supposedly, this function allows to compute confidence intervals of regression models. There are different approach, e.g. using the Wald statistic, using bootstrapped confidence intervals or using a profiler. Now, I am performing a logistic regression on a dataset of around 600,000 observations and 20 independent variables using this profiler approach. Out of statistical reasons I don't want to use Wald statistics or bootstrapping.

When I try to compute the confidence intervals, my code runs for an eternity.
So, I wondered if there is a possibility of speeding this code up by using some kind of parallel processing. I thought about an invocation of the `confint` function but calculating only the confidence intervals for one coefficient and then looping over every coefficient parallely. Unfortunately, I have not found any package that provides this. The glmmTMB package possesses a [function](https://rdrr.io/cran/glmmTMB/man/confint.glmmTMB.html) that uses parallel processing but this function is only private as can be seen [here](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/778).

Any advice concerning a special package or a workaround would be highly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Please find attached a minimal example of the original task. This is rather quick but in my original data (which is under closure atm) I have perfect separation and far longer computation times.

```
# init
set.seed(176)
# create data
y = rbinom(600000, 1, 0.2)
data = data.frame(y)
for (i in 1:20) {
  assign(paste0("x", i), rnorm(600000, i-10, i*0.1))
  data[[paste0("x", i)]] = get(paste0("x", i))
}
# calculate model
mod = glm(y ~ ., family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = data)
# calculate confidence intervals
confint(mod)
```

Based on @IRFTM's comment I also added a minimal example of my first approach in doing this parallel. But this seems rather inelegant and it also crashes with my original data as the memory explodes.

```
# calculate confidence intervals
cores = detectCores() - 1
cl = makeCluster(cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)
ci = foreach(coeff = names(coef(mod)), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
  ci_tmp = confint(mod, parm = coeff)
  ci_part = rbind(c(ci_tmp[1], ci_tmp[2]))
  rownames(ci_part) = c(coeff)
  ci_part
}
stopCluster(cl)
ci
```

Additionally, please find my sessionInfo:

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3      knitr_1.39        magrittr_2.0.3    MASS_7.3-57       tidyselect_1.1.2  R6_2.5.1          rlang_1.0.2       fastmap_1.1.0     fansi_1.0.3      
[10] stringr_1.4.0     plyr_1.8.7        httr_1.4.3        dplyr_1.0.9       tools_4.2.0       xfun_0.31         texreg_1.38.6     utf8_1.2.2        DBI_1.1.2        
[19] cli_3.3.0         htmltools_0.5.2   fastDummies_1.6.3 ellipsis_0.3.2    assertthat_0.2.1  yaml_2.3.5        digest_0.6.29     tibble_3.1.7      lifecycle_1.0.1  
[28] crayon_1.5.1      reshape2_1.4.4    tidyr_1.2.0       purrr_0.3.4       vctrs_0.4.1       glue_1.6.2        evaluate_0.15     rmarkdown_2.14    stringi_1.7.6    
[37] compiler_4.2.0    pillar_1.7.0      generics_0.1.2    renv_0.15.5       pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

P.S.: I pondered about publishing this question in statexchange but as this questions deals more with the computational part, I think this question belongs here.

Comment: Why not copy the function to your `baseenv()` (or to the default environment for each of the parallel instances?)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @IRTFM but I don't get the idea: How would you divide the above code into several code packages that can be computed in parallel?

Comment: I had assumed you knew how to set up a call to parallelized functions. Appears I was wrong. Suggest you do some searching first and then present code derived from help pages and earlier answers.

Comment: Well, yes. Actually I don't really know what you are talking about. Can you please give me a link to start my research?

Comment: `help(pac=parallel )`

Comment: Thank you. I added an example with a parallel approach. Is it this what you mean? Is there a better approach? Unfortunately, this approach closes my RStudio unexpectedly when using original data. This seems to happen in Ubuntu sometimes when the memory gets overloaded...

Comment: I am also interested in how to parallelize the process of calculating 95%ci with 200+ variables with logistic regression. Have you figured out how to do it? I have tried conditional Poisson regression and conditional logistic regression, these methods are faster than unconditional logistic regression but a strata variable needs to be defined...

Comment: @doraemon Actually no, I used asymptotic confidence intervals instead